# 6th grade question

Tags: divisibility, natural-numbers

I got this problem from some 6-th grade kid:

---

If $n=(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$, where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}^*$, then prove that

$$\frac{2^{n+1}+7^{n-1}}{15} \in \mathbb{N}$$

---

It has been some time since I tackled problems like this one so I am a bit rusty on the subject.

I tried to first see if expanding the expression of $n$ would give rise to something that can related to the expression that has to be proven. I'll put it below although it is just basic algebra.

$$n = 2abc + a^2(b+c)+ b^2(a+c) + c^2(a+b)$$

Having no hint from that result I went to the expression that has to be proven. I wrote it as

$$14\cdot 2^n + 7^n = k\cdot 105$$

where $k\in \mathbb{N}^*$. One hint came from this, but it did not deliver a solution.

I noticed that $15=2^3 + 7$ from which I can write $15 \cdot k = k(2^3 + 7)$. From this, for $k = 1$ and $k=7$, I could check by hand if I can find a value for $n$ such that it satisfies the equation that has to be proven. I got the values $n=1$ and $n=2$. However, those values cannot be written in as it is required by the first relation.

Next I thought that putting numbers for the values $a,b,c$ could give some clues. Unfortunately brute force with a calculator fails since the smallest value for $n$ is $8$, and the next one is $18$.

Note 1: This last step was also meant to check if by pure luck I can find a value for $n$ where the equation does not hold, thus solving the problem like a boss by mentioning "The problem is incorrect or it has a typo".

Note 2: I am interested in a solution that is fit for a 6-th grader, however any other level (e.g. undergraduate) should be good (I'm not a mathematician, but an engineer).

Comment: $2^{n+1}+7^{n-1}$ is always divisible by $5$, and is divisible by $3$ only if $n$ is even.

Comment: What does the * mean in $\mathbb{N}^*$?

Comment: @GEdgar, so the problem statement fails if exactly one of $a,b,c$ is odd?

Comment: @AmeetSharma Natural number without $0$.

Comment: @DerekLuna it will not because $n = (a + b) (b + c) (c + a)$ cannot be odd.

Comment: Oops, I see now that one of the terms in that case must be even.

Comment: @GEdgar Solved it. Had to remember how to prove the result you mentioned but I managed to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answer is perfectly suitable for a $6$-grader.**

First of all, note that $n$ is always even. To accept it, note that $n$ can be odd if and only if each one of $a+b$, $b+c$ and $c+a$ must be odd. If any of $a$, $b$ and $c$ is odd, then the other two must be even, implying their sum is even. Hence, $n$ is definitely even. If this sounds confusing, remember

> $$\begin{align}
> \mathrm{odd}\times \mathrm{odd}&=\mathrm{odd}\\
> \mathrm{odd}\times \mathrm{even}&=\mathrm{even}\\
> \mathrm{even}\times \mathrm{even}&=\mathrm{even}\end{align}$$

and

> $$\begin{align} \mathrm{odd}+\mathrm{even}&=\mathrm{odd}\\
> \mathrm{odd}+\mathrm{odd}&=\mathrm{even}\\
> \mathrm{even}+\mathrm{even}&=\mathrm{even}\end{align}$$

Now, comes the second part of the question. Note that
$$\frac{2^{n+1}+7^{n-1}}{15}\in\mathbb{N}\equiv 15|(2^{n+1}+7^{n-1})$$
(If you don't know the statement means that $2^{n+1}+7^{n-1}$ is exactly divisible by $15$.)

Assume, for simplicity, $x=2^{n+1}+7^{n-1}$.

To prove this, we shall do this in two parts - a number is divisible by $15$ if and only if it is divisible by both $3$ and $5$.

> A number is divisible by $5$ if and only if it ends in $5$ or $0$.

[image: See this!]

Thus, $x$ is always divisible by $5$.

Now, let's observe the remainder left by $2^{n+1}$ when divided by $3$.

[image: See this]

Thus, $2^{n+1}$ always leaves a remainder of $2$ when divided by $3$.

[image: See this]

Now, consider $7^{n-1}$.

Together, $x$ will make a remainder of $3$, which when divided by $3$ gives remainder $0$.

Thus, $x$ is exactly divisible by $3$.

**Altogether, we can say that $x$ is divisible by $15$, as required.**

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'll check the reminder part to make some sense of it and will return an answer. So far I was stuck at proving the divisibility by 3 without using induction, since it was not appropriate for a 6-th grader.

Comment: Yeah, it also took me much time to figure it out.

Comment: I googled and all the proofs I could find are related to induction. I'll let it be for now since the new problem becomes how to prove the that the reminders are as you have said without saying "we notice that...." and then imply that it stands for all even $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$.

Comment: Yeah, I thought its proof won't matter for a sixth-grader. (Unless he is damn curious, in that case, he should learn induction ;))

Comment: I don't actually see any point in doing induction here, though. It can be easily shown as $2^{n+1}+7^{n-1}\equiv -1+1\equiv 0\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 3)$, where $n$ is even.

Comment: And that modular congruences was the base of my "remainder" idea.